# RDLC data formatting in the matrix format

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, rdlc

I want to display the data in the following format in RDLC VS 2013. Tried lot but no success as of now.

```
data|data|data|data|data|data|data|data|

data|data|data|data|data|data|data|data|

data|data|data|data|data|data|data|data|
```

What I achieved was that I was able to do it in the following format.

```
data|data|data|data|data|data|data|data|
```

But then the second set of data comes in the same format as

`data|data|data|data|data|data|data|data|` but in the next page.

Comment: What? Even the edit wasn't able to save this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem. Modified the data set by populating the values in the same format. Eg., I appended the object as

123   456   789

and mapped the data-source accordingly with vertical n*1 matrix.